# Is "copywriting" a product of writing a copy?

Tags: word-usage

<sup>I don't quite understand why this question got four close votes with "unclear what you're asking" reason. I am asking if the usage of the word in the specified meaning **is acceptable**. Is it unclear what it means? An opposite of the acceptable usage might be [disputable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_with_disputed_usage). I give a specific examples when the word in question was used (which seem odd to me, hence the question). I am clueless how to further clarify my concern.</sup>

Wikipedia definition for [copywriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copywriting) says "Copywriting is **written content** conveyed through online media and print materials."

While the edit that introduced the definition is relatively recent it has already been widely quoted outside of Wikipedia. However it seems it is the source of the above definition circulating on the Internet.

**Question**: Is it acceptable to use the word "a copywriting" in the same sense as "a copy" (ie. as a product of writing, "he is renown for his copywritings")?

---

Edit: In another [occurence](http://www.benlocker.co.uk/the-best-copywriter-in-england/) ("revealed that copywriting from 1920 to the 1960s was incredibly verbose (and often dull)") the word "copywriting" is used as an uncountable noun describing the overall writings (ie. product of writing) of a particular period in time.

Comment: @macraf - As far as I can tell, your question (as edited) boils down to "Is *copywriting* a noun?" Is that right?

Comment: @JHCL No, I am not asking "is copywriting a noun," specifically I am not asking if it was a noun meaning "an art or job of copywriting".

Comment: A Google Books search for _copywritings_ returns only four confirmable matches, which suggests to me that very few authors and publishers view _copywriting_ as a countable noun. With regard to the question in your header above ("Is 'copywriting' a product of writing a copy?"), the simple answer is _no_. Rather, "copywriting" is the act or process of producing copy (that is, content). Note that _copy_, as I use it here, is not a countable noun either. The Wikipedia definition of _copywriting_ that you cite in your question misleadingly equates the task of copywriting with its product (content).

Comment: @SvenYargs Yes, that was generally my impression too, however the word seems to be used in this context here and there. That's what provoked me to ask the question. And it doesn't have to be countable to mean "content". I added another example of the word usage I found to the question.

Comment: There are four close votes because your question has been unclear and confused from the start, and it isn't really getting any clearer.  You have some basic misconceptions you need to clear up about how English works in general, and until then you should forget about "copywriting" -- you've not identified any need to use the word anyway.

Comment: @HotLicks There is no obligation to "identify any need to use the word" to ask a question if it's use was acceptable. Your comment is unrelated to this question.

Comment: If you were to provide some examples of how you expect to use the word it *might* make clearer what you're asking.  As it is, this question appears pointless.

Comment: @HotLicks Read the question. Examples are there.

Comment: You mean "he is renown for his copywritings"?  That's barely a sentence.  And, with regard to that sentence, you've already gotten the answer "NO!!".

Comment: @HotLicks No I did not mean that. Two examples of actual usage are on the question.

Comment: @hot licks If you read the linked wiki article I think you'll see why the question came up. I'm not enough of a glutton for punishment to join that conversation, but someone, somewhere thinks copywriting means a piece of written work and munged that article to say so. Someone else wants to know if we agree. I don't, do you? Do you have better evidence either way than I found? If you don't care about this question you can vote it down or ignore it.  You don't have to get into a comment war over it.

Comment: @NadjaCS - I've voted it down and voted to close, but Opie keeps raising it from the dead.  Maybe after Halloween ...

Comment: @HotLicks Your last comment (despite being written in what some would consider an aggressive tone) is manipulating facts:  Sven Yargs a few lines up posted a comment 15 hours ago and I have added additional information to the question in response to his comment.

Comment: 1) Wikipedia is knowlingly a work in progress. Using 'copyrightings' as a replacement for 'copies' is wrong. Maybe wikipedia could be changed to reflect that. 2) "Circulating on the internet"? do you have examples?

Comment: @Mitch 1) Yes. So how does it influence the grammatical/customary validity of the word in question? 2) Searching for the very phrase "Copywriting is written content conveyed through online media" yields almost 1500 results in Google and they seem all copied from the references Wikipedia article. Even if a part was created by bots, there is still a number of cases when the phrase was used in other texts. One of the reasons for asking this question was if I could uncritically (from the language usage point of view) quote the phrase.

Comment: @macraf you're talking like you think the internet is somehow an authority on some kind of truth. Just because other people copy crap don't make it better.

Comment: @Mitch The question is simple: "the word was used on wikipedia, copied widely, is it grammatically correct?" Which words qualify in your opinion to be described as "talking like I think the internet is somehow an authority on some kind of truth"?

Comment: @macraf Sorry, I thought we had already established it is wrong usage. Then you ask if a copied description (not actual usage, just the usage described by wikipedia) and copied many times, you're still asking if that means it is OK usage? That sounds like you trust repetition on the internet as truth, rather than what we're telling you here.

Comment: @Mitch You have started by posting a comment on my question asking me to clarify two points. I answered. Then you replied with another comment in which you tried to discredit your projections of my attitude towards Internet. To which I rephrased my question and flagged your comment as non constructive. Now you post a comment announcing you and someone else established a rule according to which the word usage I was asking about is wrong and still discuss with your imagination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, "copywriting" is the act of writing "copy". The "copy" of "copywriting" is not countable; if you call it "a copy", that shifts the meaning of the word to "a reproduction". The act of writing or otherwise producing a copy is generally "copying", and the product of said activity is "a copy/reproduction/facsimile".

Copy here means ["written text intended for reproduction."](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/copy) It is frequently used for advertising or media text, but not only that. For example, the contents of a book can be called "copy", and a person who edits a book for grammatical correctness (as opposed to content) is a copy editor (sometimes: copy-editor). A person who writes text that is used in journalism and advertising may be called a copywriter.

It would be rare indeed for a book author to be called a copywriter, so it is correct to say that a copywriter is writing copy for media or advertisements. It is not, however, strictly speaking correct to say that "copy" only refers to that content. It is a common term in publishing for the text body of unpublished material that is being processed for publication.

If you look at the edits and the discussion on that wiki article, you'll find there isn't consensus about how the word should be described or used and whether or not copywriting should be merged with Copy (written).

There was a change to the article around April 2015 that significantly changed the meaning of the definition and I cannot find any references to support that change. Every other definition I can find for "copywriting" defines it as an action, not the product of the action.

I believe [that wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copywriting) is wrong. [Even wiktionary defines "copywriting"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/copywriting) as the present participle of "copywrite" (that is to say: copywriting is the action of writing copy), itself listed as a backformation from copywriter (a word coined sometime around 1911 [according to Merriam-Webster)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/copywriter). None of the major dictionaries give "copywriting" its own entry, the ones that give example usages (e.g., [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/copywriter)) support my contention.

A better definition of copywriting is given by a couple of copywriter guilds.

[American Writers & Artists, Inc says:](http://www.awaionline.com/what-is-copywriting/)

> Copywriting is the process of writing advertising promotional
>   materials. Copywriters are responsible for the text on brochures,
>   billboards, websites, emails, advertisements, catalogs, and more.

[The Copywriters Freelance Collective says:](http://www.copywriters.co.za/what-is-copywriting.html)

> Copywriting is in the first instance the creative process of
>   conceptualising advertisements and marketing devices such as events
>   and other platforms promoting brands or services.

A body of written works can be called "writing" or "the writings of So-and-so", but a body of news articles or advertisements is not "copywriting" and is most definitely not "the copywritings of Whosit".

Comment: true, the point of the ngram was more in response to the other answer, not the question. The countable-uncountable is more about "copywritings vs writings", I will clear that up. But it also applies to "copy vs a copy", so I will add that in. ;-)

Comment: Somewhat [related](http://www.benlocker.co.uk/the-best-copywriter-in-england/) "revealed that copywriting from 1920 to the 1960s was incredibly verbose (and often dull)" - I am not sure if copywriting-as-a-participle or copywriting-as-an-art can be verbose or (especially) dull. If not, "copywriting" is used here in the sense of the "uncountable writing" from the previous version of your answer and it seemingly means "written content." I don't find this sentence awkward though.

Comment: I see what you mean in that context but I think it is still borderline; other uses in the same article are "copywriting was a boom industry" or "copywriting was one career" ... I think the sentence should have been "copy written from..." but it's hard to find a solid reference.

Answer (score 3):

**Copy writing** (two words) is the act of "writing copy".  "Copy" is what what newspaper and magazine editors call the stories and articles they write (perhaps because they imagine that after they've printed it, it will be so valuable it will sell many copies of their newspaper.)

Note that *copy writing* is not the same as *copyrighting*.  They are two different phrases that sound alike, but mean different things. And you will frequently see the word "copyright" misspelled as "copywrite", which isn't a valid word at all.

A copyright is the legal ownership of something you've written (literally the "right to copy"), so **copyrighting** is the act of obtaining a copyright.  For example, if you write a book, song, movie, or create a work of art, you are granted a "copyright" which gives you permission to make and sell copies of it; you also have the right to stop other people from making unauthorized copies of it or from plagiarizing it.

In general, the phrase "copy writing" should be used carefully so as not to be confused with "copyrighting".

Comment: I think this does a good job of identifying and answering the real problem behind the question, in addition to actually addressing the question as written.

Comment: to be fair, it *partially* addresses the question. It just uses 3 times as much space talking about something unrelated to the question and doesn't go into detail about why the answer is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

The previous two answers pretty much address the issue, but I fear relying too much on Wikipedia as an authority.  I'm an occasional Wikipedia editor myself, and I know that after so many years it has settled into being an admirable source of information on countless topics. But where usage is in flux, a snapshot of a single article is sometimes misleading.  The word "copywriting" seems to be in this unfortunate state, at least in some small circles.  I've written up my thoughts on that, so rather than repeat or paste them here, and if it won't be considered shameless self-promotion, I'll refer you to [*Real copywriters don't "copywrite."*](https://www.rensch.com/copywrite.html) .

Miscellaneous notes:

- Although the author of a book would not be called a copywriter, the writer of promotional or biographical flap text or back cover promotional text would be a copywriter.
- Newspaper articles have long been referred to as "copy," and the editor in charge of assigning and/or reviewing stories sits at the Copy Desk. However, in a news (or other editorial) environment, the writer of copy is ***not*** called a copywriter. He or she is a "reporter," "writer," "columnist," "author" or whatever.
- Although I bristle when I see someone naively write "copy writer" as two words (e.g, "The product description was up to the copy writer"), there have been times when even I have made it two words, almost always when referring to two titles involved in working with copy. For example, "In my career I have been a copy writer and editor." But to avoid encouraging the malinformed, I would prefer to make that "a copy editor and writer" or "copywriter and editor," even though it may slightly change the meaning. Incidentally, there is no such term as "copyeditor."  Go figure.
- As NadjaCS mentions, there are yet broader uses for the word "copy," including some that don't involve writing. For example, the original art or type that is photographed in the course of processing for printing, is called "copy." On the other hand, with xerography, the duplicate that results is the copy. As with so many things in the world, context is everything.